# DC MMF and flux density variation in space

Tags: dc, electromagnetism, magnetics, physics

If flux density produced by DC current is sinusoidally distributed in space why do we say that DC MMF is space invariant?

Answer (score 3):

MMF or magneto motive force is quite simply amps x turns. If turns remain constant and current is DC then clearly MMF is constant.

In magnetics, MMF is the driving force behind flux and certainly the flux produced by a DC current is going to tail away to insignificance at some arbitrary distance.

MMF is similar to voltage in a dc circuit with a resistor; the current taken by the resistor is equivalent to flux (not flux density) and resistance is equivalent to what we call reluctance in magnetics.

[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_reluctance) wiki article seems to explain the concepts adequately.